# consoling out django context in console

Tags: javascript, django

why am I getting output in console as `{{request.num}}` without the actual number?

This is my code:

```
def test(request):
    number = 4

    context = {"num": number}
```

*javascript*

```
var number = "{{request.num}}";
console.log(number)
```

Comment: can you provide full code?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is when I explicitly created the exact js variable inside a script tag in the template and consoled it out from the external js file, seems to work! Don't exactly know why that's happening but is.

Comment: Django only renders template variables (`context`) in the HTML template, not JS files that may be cached.